# Fill DEM with water

Tags: qgis, dem, hydrology

I want view how a volume of water calculated with Hydrologic Study, accumulates in lower parts of my DEM at 1 meter resolution. My goal it's view the level that water reaches inside the raster. It's possible in QGIS ?

---

I prefer to use SAGA GIS o GRASS GIS.

Comment: You've been here a few months, and still haven't taken the [Tour]. It, and the Help Center, emphasize how a good question will contain details of what you have attempted. GIS SE is not a tutorial site, but a problem-solving Q&A database. The answer to just about every "Is this possible with GIS?" question is "Yes", so please locate a tutorial, try to solve the problem, then,, if necessary, come back with a detailed question that specifies the software you are using and where you got stuck.

Comment: still far from enough detail in order to answer your question properly. maybe let people know what sort of data you want to visualise, what you've tried and where you're stuck

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about SAGA or QGIS in this particular question.  That way you are able to describe in detail what you have tried and where you are stuck with that software.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a raster surface of the percipitation in the area of interest, a raster layer with the Water Permeability values for each rock and a DEM which you already have.

You can use [Hydrology Analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-hydrology-tools.htm)  available in ArcGIS's Spatial Analyst Toolbox and Raster Calculator for the evaluations.

ArcGIS is a Commercial software so if you need an opensource solution check this QGIS [Hydrological Analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html) instead.

Comment: No I dont have a ESRI software. I use only open source software.
Thanks

Comment: You should always mention the software you are asking about. You initial question said "is it possible in GIS software, that's why you're having various answers